# Ansi C complains about array initializing

Tags: arrays, c, initialization, ansi-c

I have a simple C program that compiles fine under c99, but under ANSI it complains:

***missing braces around initializer***

The offending line is:

```
int myarr[3][3]={0};
```

Why is ANSI C complaining?  I saw one posting saying to add additional { } around the { 0 } but that makes no sense to me...

(I'm compiling in CentOS in case it matters)

Comment: Why is adding another set of braces counter intuitive? Its a 2d array, one set of braces per dimension?...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly (under ANSI C) you should additional curly braces if you were to initialising a multi-dimensional array. For example if one initialises  each element to a specific value one would do the following:

```
int myarr[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
```

Comment: It is maybe better to add them but C does not requires you to add the inner braces here. See 6.7.8p26 in C99.

Answer (score 3):

```
int myarr[3][3]={0};
```

This is perfectly valid C, the warning is just an indication from your compiler in this case.

If you want to get rid of the warning you can do:

```
int myarr[3][3]={{0}};
```

or also add `-Wno-missing-braces` if you are using `gcc` with `-Wall` options.

Comment: OK got it.  My teacher requires no other compiler options so I'll have to add the extra braces.